# pysaml2 usage - Missing entity_id specification

Tags: python, saml, saml-2.0

What is the proper format for data to initialize the pysaml2 client? The library complains that `Missing entity_id specification`, despite there being an `entityID` in the xml (below).

```py
spConfig = Saml2Config()
spConfig.load({
    'metadata': {
        'inline': [idp_metadata],
    },
    'service': {
        'sp': {
            'endpoints': {
                'assertion_consumer_service': [
                    (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                    (acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    (https_acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                    (https_acs_url, BINDING_HTTP_POST)
                ],
            },
            # Don't verify that the incoming requests originate from us via
            # the built-in cache for authn request ids in pysaml2
            'allow_unsolicited': True,
            # Don't sign authn requests, since signed requests only make
            # sense in a situation where you control both the SP and IdP
            'authn_requests_signed': False,
            'logout_requests_signed': True,
            'want_assertions_signed': True,
            'want_response_signed': False,
        },
    },
})
saml_client = Saml2Client(config=spConfig)
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor
  entityID="http://www.okta.com/[redacted]" 
  xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
...
```

The library version is the most recent. `python` 3.10 running on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: pysaml2 wanted an extra parameter:

```py
settings = {
        'metadata': {
            'inline': [idp_metadata],
        },
        'entityid': ...
```

The documentation god awful and it's very unclear whether this is a full solution.